# Does "frech wie Oskar sein" have a negative connotation to it?

Tags: idiom, connotation

Does the following sentence have negative connotation? If it does, is there an equivalent without the negative connotation?

> „Du bist ja frech wie Oskar!“

As I searched, none of the following sources talked about the connotation:

- [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frech_wie_Oskar)
- [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Oskar)
- [DWDS](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=Oskar)
- [Leo](http://dict.leo.org/ende?lp=ende&lang=de&searchLoc=0&cmpType=relaxed&sectHdr=on&spellToler=&search=Oskar)
- [Dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc/?s=frech%20wie%20oskar)
- (Not even) [German Language and Usage](https://german.stackexchange.com/search?q=Oskar)

Comment: I think the word "frech" in general (and similar to "cheeky") doesn't have much of a negative connotation to it any more.

Comment: I beg to differ. I am a native German, 31 years old, living in Berlin and to me "frech" is by default negative. There is a number of use cases where it is not but if you just call a person "frech" this is negative to me.

Comment: @StefanoPalazzo: Think about how somebody would describe shady/impudent business practices (using *frech* as an alternative to *unverschämt* or *dreist*). I can't say I know what the current "default" connotation is, but I respectfully disagree with your generalization towards an almost exclusively positive meaning of *frech*.

Comment: Well - there is the original meaning of 'frech' - it means what it does; I don't think there is a disagreement here. Why do we have to talk about a connotation?

Comment: Fair point, well made @Emanuel. I should have said "not offensive" - it is *of course* a negative word, but by no means an affront, generally speaking, even thought there are situations where it can be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We should point out that it may well be possible that *"Oskar"* originated from Jiddish *ossik* or *Ossoker* but this view seems not yet scientifically proven. Other explanations are that it may be a reference to [Oscar Blumethal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oscar_Blumenthal) ([Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Oskar)) a sharp tongued and humorous Berlin critic. From the closeness to other idioms that use *Bolle* it may also be that just a common name was randomly chosen.

*"Frech"* is definitely not only used with a negative connotation as it would be the case when a teacher talks about her pupils. It is also widely use to depict someone (ore something) as being a bit off the mainstream, lively, cool, or fresh.

Examples for this usage are:

> Pippi Longstocking is considered as *frech* but then also in the most positive way.
>   *"Eine freche Frisur"*: is a cool or fresh haircut.
>   *"Ich mag Anna mit ihren frechen Antworten sehr"*

Therefore by shifting *"frech"* to colloquial when saying *"frech wie Oskar"* we simultaneously shift the meaning towards a more positive connotation too. But this of course always depends on context.

Comment: +1 for the point that "frech" shifted it's meaning quite a bit. I would add to the positive meanings of "frech" the aspect of "not shy, self confident".
I'm thinking of this rule of thumb: If somebody could be considered cute in a way, "frech" has the possibility to have a positive meaning.

Answer (score 4):

I think [this article](http://www.gfds.de/sprachberatung/fragen-und-antworten/uebersichtsseite/frech-wie-oskar/) from the GfdS gives a good hint in its last paragraph where it speaks of a tautology, since Oskar can be derived from the Jiddish expression *ossok* for *frech*, so an *Ossoker* is a person who is *frech* by default and calling him *frech* again makes it even stronger, which again is enough to give the expression a negative connotation.

Comment: Without knowing Oscar, the strucutre of the sentence makes him "frech" by default ;)